# Jenkins - previous build artifacts are lost

Tags: jenkins

So, what I'm doing:

**Build n:**

1. Cleaning a MODULE_NAME/test-output/* in ***workspace*** explicitly with ant
2. Running build and tests, getting some artifacts into folder from step one
3. Jenkins runs archive artifacts step for MODULE_NAME/test-output/*
4. Now artifacts are stored in **build n** - works for me.

**Now build n+1 launching:**

1. Cleaning a MODULE_NAME/test-output/* in ***workspace*** explicitly with ant
2. Checking artifacts from build n - they're still there, as expected.
3. Running build and tests, getting some artifacts into workspace folder from step one...
4. Jenkins runs archive artifacts step for MODULE_NAME/test-output/*
5. Now artifacts are stored in **build n+1** - works for me, if not the next.

**The problems** is that, for some reason, artifacts from **build n** are lost.

My post-build actions:

[image: Any suggestions?]

How do I keep unique artifacts for each build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the problem that bothered us for so long was in here: [image: facepalm.pdf]

Not sure if I recall this in older versions of jenkins.

I'm so confused.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because in Max # you mentioned 1 so it'll clean artifacts after 1 build either increase that number or just uncheck "Discard Old Builds". You can write some post build script which will clear these artifacts after certain builds.